# Why is my Makefile not creating my .o file C++

Tags: c++, makefile

My professor assigned a programming assignment and gave us the Makefile to build it. The problem is when I build it, it diplays this message

```
g++: error: SortedListArrayDriver.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'SA' failed
mingw32-make: *** [SA] Error 1
```

Here is the makefile that he has provided for us

```
AutomatedMakefile = am
CC = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -O0

PROJECT_PATH = $(CURRENT_DIR)
GUI_PATH = $(DRIVE_LETTER)/TDM-GCC-64/wxWidgets-3.1.0

INC_DIRS = -I./1310/CSC1310 -I./1310/GUI -I$(GUI_PATH)/include -
I$(GUI_PATH)/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/mswu
LIB_DIRS = -L./1310/CSC1310 -L./1310/GUI -L$(GUI_PATH)/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Bstatic
LIBS = $(LDFLAGS) -lCSC1310 -lrandom -lGUI -lwxmsw31u_core -lwxbase31u -
lgdi32

COMPILE = $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_DIRS) -c 
LINK = $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIB_DIRS)

FILES1 =SortedListArrayDriver.o
EXECUTABLE1 = SLADriver.exe

all: SA

SA:  $(FILES)
 $(LINK) $(FILES1) $(LIBS) -o $(EXECUTABLE1)

SortedListArrayDriver.o: SortedListArray.h
    $(COMPILE) SortedListArrayDriver.cpp
```

I really don't know what i'm doing wrong and any help would be appreciated

Comment: Read documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Tabs are significant in `Makefile`s. Run `make --trace`. Use  [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/). Consider installing a Linux distribution on your computer (it is much more developer and student friendly). Your *fix-my-`Makefile`-code* request is off-topic on StackOverflow. Your question should have some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you should edit it to improve it

Comment: If you've modified it, put it back the way it was. Then it's his fault. If you have a file called `SortedListArray.cpp` it should work. However the makefile is certainly wrong not to include `SortedListArray.cpp` as a dependency of `SortedListArray.o`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The makefile *is* the MCVE.

Comment: @EJP: Are you able to `make` with this makefile on your own computer? I am not (because some `*.cpp` files are lacking, because I don't have any `./1310/CSC1310` directory containing headers, etc). So sadly this is *not* a MCVE!

Comment: "SA:  $(FILES)" should be "SA:  $(FILES1)".

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, because I don't have `gcc++` or`make` installed, *or* a file called `SortedListArray.cpp`, which is one of the points at issue, *or* the directories you mention, which can be easily remedied, and which is completely immaterial. I don't need them. I can read the makefile. Can you?

Comment: @EJP "C" in MCVE stands for "complete".

Comment: @J.Nic: I recommend to rewrite entirely your `Makefile` from scratch. It would be faster than trying to fix it. But you need to learn more about `make`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm sorry I didn't supply enough information. There isn't a *.cpp file for SortedListArray.h because it's a templated class. Changing "SA:$(FILES)" to "SA:$(FILES1)" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous errors in this makefile. Complain to your professor. Show him this page.